# Potential solution to Bug #1573052 (Gnome-software crash due to broken dependency link)

Tags: gnome, package-management, software-center, 16.04

I cannot open `gnome-software`. Here is the error message:

```
$ gnome-software
(gnome-software:3824): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: 
/usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

- [The bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573052)

I have been grappling with this for some time. I have tried reinstalling and that didn't work. The file shows in my directory in red, I search through the properties and it says that it is broken/missing. I opened it in gedit, and it opened up blank. So after all of that I deleted it figuring updating and upgrading might be the solution. It was not. Now I would like to do one of two things:

1. reinstall `gs-plugins` without breaking the rest of my system
2. just install the missing file in gs-plugins (can't find it)

Or is there an alternative that I am not aware of? Could someone with more experience give me some guidance on how to carry out one of those two options or how I should go about solving the problem? Thank you.

Comment: The file is apparently from the [`gnome-software` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so) itself.

Comment: Any Ideas on how to fix it? If you could post your *review.so (not sure if that is the proper way to refer to it in a shorthand manner) file so I can copy-paste it into mine to see if it works that would be awesome. I can't find it anywhere so I don't know what to put it in the text file to make it work.

Comment: A `.so` file is not text, it's a compiled shared library file. You can download the gnome-software package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gnome-software/download (change amd64 to the correct architecture if you aren't using amd64) then extract the file from it.